# Cordova plugin, using javascript to start an android service

Tags: javascript, java, android, cordova

I have some issues developing my own plugin. I want my plugin to run as a background process on an android device. Searching the internet, I found using the Service superclass (or a sub-class) being most relevant. Below is some sample code, the execute method in Hello.java is successfully called - the app crashes when I try to start the service (the constructor is successfully instantiated though). Any hints?

```
//Myservice.java
public class MyService extends IntentService {
    public MyService(String name) {
        super(name);
        Log.d("asd", "constructor");
    }

    @Override
    public void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.d("asd", "something");
    }
}

//Hello.java
public class Hello extends CordovaPlugin {
    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray data, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
        Log.d("asd", "we are in execute, hurray!");
        Context context = cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);            
        MyService service = new MyService("WifiP2pService");            
        //either this
        service.startService(intent);
        //or this, tried both
        //context.startService(intent);
        return true;
    }
}

// /plugins/the.package/www/hello.js
module.exports = {
    greet: function (name, successCallback, errorCallback) {
        cordova.exec(successCallback, errorCallback, "Hello", "greet", [name]);
    }
};

// /www/index.js - in onDeviceReady function
var success = function(message) {
    alert(message);
}

var failure = function() {
    alert("Error calling the plugin");
}

hello.greet("Superdids", success, failure);
```

I am fairly new to android programming, so any hints would be muchly appreciated!